# Mottie - JQuery Virtual Keyboard does not bind AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to use [Mottie's Virtual Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) with AngularJS and here is the [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvtofn6L/80/).

The result turns out that the input from the keyboard does not bind to the controller. Any idea how to fix this?

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrap" ng-controller="myController">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myController.firstName" 
           placeholder="Input first name here" />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="keyboard" type="text" ng-model="myController.lastName" 
           placeholder="input last name here" />
    <br/><br/>          
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:yellow">
      {{myController.firstName}}
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:lightblue">
      {{myController.lastName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
angular.module('portal', []).controller('myController', 
    function ($scope) {
        $('#keyboard').keyboard({
            visible: function(e, keyboard, el) {
                  keyboard.$preview[0].select();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard doesn't set the INPUT field, so you need to get the value from the keyboard and set it in your Angular controller and change your binding to the scope:

js:

```
angular.module('portal', []).controller('myController', 
    function ($scope) {
        $('#keyboard').keyboard({
            visible: function(e, keyboard, el) {
                  keyboard.$preview[0].select();
            },
            beforeClose: function(e, keyboard, el, accepted) {   
                  this.lastName = this.value;
                  $scope.$apply();
                        },
        }
    );
});
```

html:

```
<div id="wrap" ng-controller="myController">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" 
           placeholder="Input first name here" />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="keyboard" type="text" ng-model="lastName" 
           placeholder="input last name here" />
    <br/><br/>          
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:yellow">
      {{firstName}}
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:lightblue">
      {{lastName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/groov/8z2scgLo/

You might want to checkout the Angular variant, https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard